# Data Annotations not overriding configurationBuilder properties

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

In my `DbContext`, I am setting all strings to `varchar(250)`, but I have some strings marked as `varchar(max)"`. After creating my migrations, I see the tables marked as max are still being created with a max length of 250.

How can I have my data annotations override the config builder command?

Config builder:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Properties<string>()
                        .HaveColumnType("varchar(250)")
                        .AreUnicode(false);
}
```

Entity:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(max)")]
    public string? AffectedColumns { get; set; }
```

What is generated in the migration:

```
AffectedColumns = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(250)", unicode: false, nullable: true)
```

Comment: According to [this MS docs article (for EF Core 6)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/), I'm afraid you **cannot**: *You can also apply attributes (known as Data Annotations) to your classes and properties. Data annotations will override conventions, but will be overridden by Fluent API configuration.* - not sure if anything has changed in EF Core **7** in this regard

Comment: Is the config builder conisdered fluent API?

Comment: Maybe `HasColumnType`?

Comment: So i looked at your likk and they are yalking about modlebuilder which is different from configurationbuilde (from what i can tell). So o dont know if that applies. I will be posting to the git lab for help

Comment: Yes, using the `ConfigurationBuilder` **IS** the FluentAPI

Answer (score 1):

EFCore 7 introduces finalizing conventions.  It looks like the part you're looking for is here:
[Default length for all string properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#example-default-length-for-all-string-properties)

You need to put your varchar(250) convention in the `ProcessModelFinalizing` method.  Finalizing Conventions only apply if an object has not already been configured.  A configuration applied by a data annotation (varchar(Max)) would be skipped by the finalizing convention and would not change it to varchar(250).

```
public class DefaultStringLengthFinalizingConvention : IModelFinalizingConvention
{
  public void ProcessModelFinalizing(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext<IConventionModelBuilder> context)
  {
    foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Metadata.GetEntityTypes()
                 .SelectMany(
                     entityType => entityType.GetDeclaredProperties()
                     .Where(property => !property.IsForeignKey())
                     .Where(property => property.ClrType == typeof(string))))
    {
      property.Builder.HasMaxLength(250);
      property.Builder.IsUnicode(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your DbContext class, add:

```
  protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
  { 
    //finalizing conventions are processed in order, last convention wins conflicts
    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Add(_ => new DefaultStringLengthFinalizingConvention());
  }
```

Note that my DefaultStringLengthConvention explicitly excludes Foreign Key properties.  A FK should always match the PK definition.

Comment: That's a very generic answer. How should these conventions be used to solve OP's problem?

Comment: @GertArnold Its part of my answer.  Using this approach, he can set a default convention of varchar(250) as well as explicitly configure a property, such as varchar(max).  The finalizing convention does not apply to any property that has an explicit convention set and would be ignored when the model is built.  This is new for EF7.

Comment: But the primary question is: "How can I have my data annotations override the config builder command?" Since that apparently doesn't work, what should they do specifically in *their* code? What I mean is, when applied to their case it'll be clear that using a convention is more complicated than just adding one fluent API instruction.

Comment: @GertArnold - What they should do in their code is create a finalizing convention to set a default of varchar(250) .  Any explicit configurations or data annotations would override that setting when the model is built.

Comment: So you finally did what I was pointing at all along: apply it to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You're using [Pre-convention configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration#pre-convention-configuration) here. The current documentation doesn't explicitly state how this type of configuration collaborates with model configuration, i.e. fluent API (configuration classes and `OnModelCreating` overrides) and data annotations, but it does say

> This configuration is performed before a model is created.

Which indicates that model configuration overrules it. And yes, it does.

However, in my tests, only the fluent API does so consistently. Data annotations are messy (not only in Entity Framework). For example, `[StringLength(20)]` overrides the length, `[Unicode(true)]` does *not* override the `varchar` datatype and `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(max)")]` (or `[DataType("nvarchar(max)")]`) does *not* override the length nor the data type.

Which means: *always* use fluent API to model exceptions to the conventions:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
    .Property(e => e.AffectedColumns)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

Comment: EFCore 7 intoduced finalizing conventions to address this very issue, and they can be used with data annotations.

Comment: It is valid for EFC6 and below, but the question was tagged with EFCore 7.  Data Annotations work just fine with Finalizing Conventions.

Comment: As I said, as long as pre-convention configuration exists it's good to be aware of its limitations. There's nothing wrong with this answer.